# How can I add text to an image in a 3d carousel

Tags: jquery, html, carousel, jcarousel

Trying to add captions and links, plus make the image stop when you hover over it.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery.k3dCarousel.min.js"></script>
        <style>
            #k3dCarousel img{
                display:none;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="k3dCarousel">
            <img src="image1.jpg" />
            <img src="image2.jpg" />
            <img src="image3.jpg" />
            <img src="image4.jpg" />
            <img src="image5.jpg" />
            <img src="image6.jpg" />
            <img src="image7.jpg" />
            <img src="image8.jpg" />
        </div>
        <script>
            $(window).load(function(){
                $('#k3dCarousel').k3dCarousel();
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Demo can be seen at: http://demo.verens.com/k3dCarousel/demo.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this slider [RoundAbout Slider](http://fredhq.com/projects/roundabout/). This seems to be a perfect slider with lots of customizations.

Comment: Thanks, but don't like this one.